# TO save data to hidden div using jStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I am using jStorage to store data in local storage .. i store data in console.log() when i retrieve data using $.jStorage.get() the values are not assign to the hidden div so how can i assign value to hidden div

Comment: The first thing you do is [**write a proper question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

To assign data to a HTML DOM element, you can use the [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function as such:

```
// Assign data
$('.myHiddenElement').data('dataKey', 'Some data goes here! :)');

// Get the data
var storedData = $('.myHiddenElement').data('dataKey'); // == 'Some data goes here! :)'
```

However it's **very** unclear of what you are asking for. This is just my assumption.